# simple xml outputting data in specific order

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have what I hope is a simple question, but I cant find any useful info on this online.

I have an xml file:

```
<market id="27719037" name="Wolves v Leeds">
<participant name="home" id="121081062" odds="7/2"/>
<participant name="Draw" id="121081062" odds="7/2"/>
<participant name="away" id="121081062" odds="7/2"/>
</market>

<market id="27719037" name="Liverpool v Fulham">
<participant name="Draw" id="121081062" odds="7/2"/>
<participant name="home" id="121081062" odds="7/2"/>
<participant name="away" id="121081062" odds="7/2"/>
</market>
```

Because the XML is outputted in a different order for each market game I cant simply rely on outputting it in order.

Is there a way I can specificall pull out:

home odds
draw odds
away odds?

thanks in advance

richard

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$xml= simplexml_load_file('temp.xml');

$xmlarr = array();

$i=0;
foreach($xml as $market) {
foreach($market as $participant){
    $name =  (string)$participant['name'];
    //to store in pairs of 'home odds' 'draw odds' 'away odds'
    $xmlarr[$i][$name] = (string)$participant['odds'];

 }
    ++$i;    
  }
```

Now you have `$xmlarr` array whose structure will look like this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["home"]=>
    string(3) "7/2"
    ["Draw"]=>
    string(3) "7/2"
    ["away"]=>
    string(3) "7/2"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Draw"]=>
    string(3) "7/2"
    ["home"]=>
    string(3) "7/2"
    ["away"]=>
    string(3) "7/2"
  }
}
```

You can access them in your desired order like this:

```
foreach ($xmlarr as $element) {
 echo "home : ".$element ['home']."<br>";
 echo "Draw : ".$element ['Draw']."<br>";
 echo "away : ".$element ['away']."<br>"; 
 }
```

o/p

```
home : 7/2
Draw : 7/2
away : 7/2
home : 7/2
Draw : 7/2
away : 7/2
```

When you access `['home']` you will get the `odd` relevant to it. Silmilarly for `['Draw']` & `['away']`.